# ASP.NET Core routing fails to match route parameter, duplicated route parameter in API explorer

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0, .net-5

Having this code:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
}

[Route("/api/intakes/{​​​​​​​​intakeId}​​​​​​​​/employees/")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<object>> GetEmployees([FromRoute]int intakeId)
    {
        return new[] { new { a = "asdsf", id = intakeId } };
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access `GET /api/intakes/5/employees/`, but the route is not matched.

The log:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:5000/api/intakes/5/employees/ - -
Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware: Trace: All hosts are allowed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Debug: 1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/api/intakes/5/employees/'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Debug: Endpoint 'WebApplication3.EmployeesController.GetEmployees (WebApplication3)' with route pattern 'api/intakes/{​​​​​​​​intakeId}​​​​​​​​/employees' was rejected by complex segment '{​​​​​​​​intakeId}​​​​​​​​' for the request path '/api/intakes/5/employees/'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher: Debug: Endpoint 'WebApplication3.EmployeesController.GetEmployees (WebApplication3)' with route pattern 'api/intakes/{​​​​​​​​intakeId}​​​​​​​​/employees' is not valid for the request path '/api/intakes/5/employees/'
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware: Debug: Request did not match any endpoints
```

What's strange is that in the API explorer I can see 2 `intakeId` parameters for this route

[image: API explorer]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to apply [route constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#route-constraint-reference) to restrict parameter `intakeId`, like below.

```
[Route("api​​​​​​​​/intakes/{intakeId:int}/employees/")]
[ApiController]
public class EmployeesController : ControllerBase
{
```